# PHP need to reach the main parent

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a PHP code to find the parent of a category and to echo the `parent_id`,
It works fine, but if this parent has a parent I need it to keep looping till it finds the main parent which should have `category_parent = 0`, can any one tell me how to do that?

PHP

```
$query_rsCategoryId = "SELECT * FROM categories 
WHERE category_id = '".$_REQUEST['category_id']."'";
$rsCategoryId = mysql_query($query_rsCategoryId, $connection);
$row_rsCategoryId = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategoryId);

do {
    $query_rsParent = "SELECT * FROM categories 
          WHERE category_id = '".$row_rsCategoryId['category_parent']."'";
    $rsParent = mysql_query($query_rsParent, $connection);
    $row_rsParent = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsParent);
    $totalRows_rsParent = mysql_num_rows($rsParent);

    if ($totalRows_rsParent > 0 ){
      echo $row_rsParent['category_id'];
    }
} while ($row_rsCategoryId = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategoryId));
```

Comment: go recursive. call the same function, make sure you exit the loop in the worst case at least.

Comment: i have no idea how to do recursive function!

Comment: @NasserKamal Ah it's pretty simple to [learn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/234868/3933332)

Comment: you can do it with sql query, can you describe your CATEGORIES Table ?

Comment: my Categories table "category_id, category_name, category_parent " ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getParent($id) {    
  $query_rsCategoryId = "SELECT * FROM categories 
  WHERE category_id = '".$_REQUEST['category_id']."'";
  $rsCategoryId = mysql_query($query_rsCategoryId, $connection);
  $row_rsCategoryId = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCategoryId);
  $parent = $row_rsCategoryId['category_parent'];
  if (mysql_num_rows($rsCategoryId) < 1) {
    // Error handling, entry with id $id not found
    return null;
  }
  if ($parent == 0) {
    return $id;
  } else {
    return getParent($parent);
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: Not tested in any way.*

However this assumes that if your entry has no parent, it's his own parent.

And of course, `mysql_*` is deprecated. Make sure to look into `mysqli` and `PDO`.

**Be aware that this can lead to a huge IO bottleneck, since we are doing 1 query for every step up the trace it has to go**

---

edit: Usage with your POST parameter:

```
echo getParent($_GET['category_id']);
```

assuming you have the get param set.

Comment: thanks , please tell me how to call this function to use the parent id should i do <?php echo getParent($id); ?>

Comment: exactly like you wrote in your comment :) `echo getParent(4)` is supposed to echo the main parent of category with id 4.

Comment: but when i do i get error says Undefined variable: id !

Comment: You need to pass it a valid id. like I mentioned: `getParent(4)`.

Comment: i can't pass a valid id i need to know the main parent id of the $_REQUEST['category_id']; for example if url = products.php?category_id=3 then its parent should be 1, then your function should echo 1

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: categories 
(id=1 , name=Hand made, parent=0)
(id=2 , name=Factory made, parent=0)
(id=3 , name=chairs, parent=1)
(id=4 , name=tabels, parent=1)
(id=5 , name=old chairs, parent=3)

so if visitor clicked on Old Chairs, will go to page products.php?category_id = 5

then at this page i need to know what is the main category id , which should be HAND made with category_id=1

so at this page i want to say 
if isset($_REQUEST['category_id']){
do the function till find the main parent 
and set $mainparentid = main parent category_id
}else {
$mainparentid = '';
}
echo $mainparentid;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71493/discussion-between-nasser-kamal-and-sbls).